# android how to draw a circle on google map

Tags: android

I am using the new API(Google Map API V2) for my android application, i have done creating the map and adding markers to it, now my task is to manually create a circle around any of the marker and also i want to provide a functionality to the user that he can increase the radius of that circle accordingly, for this i have given a bar, when user increases that bar the radius of circle will increase and vice versa.

If anybody knows how to do this using Google Map API V2 then please help,

Answer (score 32):

try this code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_tag_map);

     // Drawing circle on the map
           drawCircle(new LatLng(Latitude, Longitude));
    }

        private void drawCircle(LatLng point){

                // Instantiating CircleOptions to draw a circle around the marker
                CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions();

                // Specifying the center of the circle
                circleOptions.center(point);

                // Radius of the circle
                circleOptions.radius(20);

                // Border color of the circle
                circleOptions.strokeColor(Color.BLACK);

                // Fill color of the circle
                circleOptions.fillColor(0x30ff0000);

                // Border width of the circle
                circleOptions.strokeWidth(2);

                // Adding the circle to the GoogleMap
                googleMap.addCircle(circleOptions);

            }
```

Comment: yes it good but my task is to manage the marker circle from the seek bar

Comment: public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
             boolean fromUser) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            pro=progress;
              googleMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
                             .center(new LatLng(point.latitude,point.longitude))
                             .radius(pro)
                             .strokeWidth(0f)
                             .fillColor(0x550000FF)
                             
                             );

Comment: How would you make it so the circle remains in the center of the map as the user moves across the map?

Answer (score 22):

Add the following code in `onMapReady()` method:

```
Circle circle = map.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
     .center(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
     .radius(10000)
     .strokeColor(Color.RED)
     .fillColor(Color.BLUE));
```

where `map` is the object of `GoogleMap` class.

Answer (score 4):

Google Maps can use semi-transparent color for the circle.

```
private var circle: Circle? = null

private fun drawCircle(latitude: Double, longitude: Double, radius: Double) {
    val circleOptions = CircleOptions()
        .center(LatLng(latitude, longitude))
        .radius(radius)
        .strokeWidth(1.0f)
        .strokeColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context!!, R.color.color1))
        .fillColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context!!, R.color.color2))
    circle?.remove() // Remove old circle.
    circle = googleMap?.addCircle(circleOptions) // Draw new circle.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin version of @Lalit Kushwah

```
map.addCircle(
    CircleOptions()
        .center([Your LatLng])
        .radius(10000.0)
        .strokeColor(Color.RED)
        .fillColor(Color.BLUE)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
             CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions();
                circleOptions.center(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude()));
                circleOptions.radius(700);
                circleOptions.fillColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                circleOptions.strokeWidth(6);
                mMap.addCircle(circleOptions);
            geocoder = new Geocoder(MapsActivity.this, getDefault());
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            markerOptions.position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
            mMap.addMarker(markerOptions.title(String.valueOf(location)));
```

try this

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.